# Show that if $(S,d_S)$ is complete then $S$ is a closed subset of $X$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $S$ a subset of $X$. Then if $(S,d_S)$ is complete then $S$ is a closed subset of $X$.

I'm reading a proof of this proposition and it says

Suppose $x_n\in S$ with $x_n\to x$. Then $x_n$ is Cauchy in $S$ so converges to some $y\in S$. **

Since $x_n,y\in S$ it follows that $d|_S(x_n,y)=d(x_n,y)$ so $x_n\to y$ in $X$, i.e $x=y$ and $S$ is closed.

My question is why can't we conclude that $x=y$ from **? What does the second part actually tell us?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proof you're reading is using the "sequential" definition of closed sets, ie: $S$ is closed iff it contains all its limit points. So, for any converging sequence $(x_n)$, its limit has to be in $S$. So your proof assumes $x_n \longrightarrow x$.

Then: $(x_n)$ is Cauchy, so it has a limit $y \in S$ by definition of completeness (that is your first step).

Now, you assumed that $x_n \to x$. So implicitly, your second step uses the fact that in a metric space, the limit is unique. So $x = y$ :)

Comment: So we do the second part because $(S,d_S)$ isn't a metric space itself?

Comment: You only need the fact that $S \subseteq X$, and $X$ is a metric space. So "treated as a sequence of X", $(x_n)$ has a unique limit (that's a property of metric spaces). So it has to be also true in $S$ :)

Answer (score 0):

We cannot conclude $x=y$ from $(**)$ because we do not know $x\in S$. It is only after we show $x_n\to y$ in $X$ that we must have $x=y$ because limits are unique.